# Understanding Valgrind o/p

Tags: valgrind, memcheck

I am running memcheck using valgrind. 
the o/p is

```
==3091== 204 bytes in 17 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1,406 of 2,299
```

what does it mean ?

What I guess there is `204 bytes memory loss`

but what it meant by

```
17 blocks ?
```

and how to know how many time this memory leak happened by same function ?

Complete stack trace of the valgrind

```
==3091== 204 bytes in 17 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1,406 of 2,299
==3091==    at 0x4A05E1C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==3091==    by 0x4CA304: fs_get (fs_unix.c:38)
==3091==    by 0x4E58C1: cpystr (misc.c:74)
==3091==    by 0x4D130F: ip_nametoaddr (ip_unix.c:178)
==3091==    by 0x4D15F4: tcp_open (tcp_unix.c:192)
==3091==    by 0x4D41A5: cc_connect_http_proxy (proxy.c:164)
==3091==    by 0x4D4B0C: cc_connect (proxy.c:571)
==3091==    by 0x4D506D: ssl_open (osdep.c:353)
==3091==    by 0x4E56C3: net_open_work (mail.c:6240)
==3091==    by 0x4E558A: net_open (mail.c:6196)
==3091==    by 0x4FBA04: imap_open (imap4r1.c:841)
==3091==    by 0x4D9CB1: mail_open_work (mail.c:1355)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that there were 17 different calls to `malloc` (or another allocator function) whose return was not `free`'d. Those 17 allocations represented a total of 204 bytes being lost.

Comment: so the function which is calling malloc is only called one time right ?. as it is only one time.

Comment: I don't know your code, so I can't answer that comment. valgrind is telling you that 17 separate calls to allocator functions were made without a corresponding deallocation.

Comment: I updated my question with full stack trace. I am using c-client lib on it's function call it is showing that message. 
I am not sure is it one time memory leak or every time it is leaking .

Comment: That does not change a thing. That specific path in your code happened at least 17 times, and the allocations from that malloc were not freed 17 times.